# How do you programatically create a custom LinearLayout where the height is a certain percentage of the width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a custom `LinearLayout` where the height is 80% of the width.

I created a class that extends LinearLayout and overrides `onMeasure()`.  I thought I could manipulate the passed-in widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec, but all I get is a  LinearLayout with no height.

Actually, I have a TextView in it, so all I see is the TextView with no other height applied to the layout.

I'm hoping someone can tell me what's wrong with this:

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {

        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int adjustedHeight = (int) (MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 0.8); 
        int measureSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int adjustedHeightMeasureSpec = 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(adjustedHeight, measureSpecMode);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, adjustedHeightMeasureSpec);           
    }    
}
```

EDIT: Okay, this is strange.  The code decided to work after I restarted Eclipse and ran it again.

Answer (score 1):

You should change mode to exactly, like :

```
int measureSpecMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue might be that the height that the layout calculates is based on the children, i.e. the layout will be taller the more stuff it has in it.

One obvious problem with your code however is that you have not called

```
setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, adjustedHeightMeasureSpec);
```

in the `onMeasure()` method. You instead still have the super.onMeasure. In order for your custom measured heights and widths to be used you have to call this method. In fact you can delete the last line of your code in onMeasure and replace it with the line above.

Comment: I replace the call to `super()` with the call to `setMeasureDimension()` and while the layout height does size correctly, it has no content (the TextView is invisible).  Anyway, the code I originally posted is somehow working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, (int)(widthMeasureSpec*0.8));           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to adjust your layouts height to any ratio:

```
private static final float RATIO = 80f / 100f;

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int widthWithoutPadding = width - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int heigthWithoutPadding = height - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

    int maxWidth = (int) (heigthWithoutPadding * RATIO);
    int maxHeight = (int) (widthWithoutPadding / RATIO);

    if (widthWithoutPadding > maxWidth) {
        width = maxWidth + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    } else {
        height = maxHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

}
```

You can vary the `RATIO` constant according to your need.